# how to escape $ in robots.txt Disallow directive?

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot, google-crawlers

robots.txt handles the `$` as a special character to identify the end of the pattern.

Though, googlebot is parsing some hrefs from JS templates within script tags e.g:

```
<a href="${object.path}"> ${object.name}</a>
```

After encoding it, google bot tries to reach `mySite.com/$%7Bobject.path%7D` which ends in 404s.

To work around this I want do disallow such urls from being crawled by adding a matching directive to my robots.txt.

But using the $ "as is" doesn't work:

```
Disallow: /$%7Bobject.path%7D$
```

The only working solution I found was to use the wildcard character:

```
Disallow: /*%7Bobject.path%7D$
```

Though, I'm really curious if there is a way to escape that particular $ sign?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Well after some more testing with the google robots.txt testing tool I have some strange results. According to this tool the directive:

```
Disallow: /*%7Bobject.path%7D$
```

won't work for `/$%7Bobject.path%7D` while other tools tells me it matches (like https://technicalseo.com/seo-tools/robots-txt/).

What works in google's testing tool is putting the brackets unencoded in the directive:

```
Disallow: /*{object.path}$
```

I can't make any sense out of it so I've put both version in my robots.txt.

Comment: I have urls I want to block that have a literal `*`, it looks like we're out of luck

Answer (score 0):

Googlebot and other crawlers support the `$` but it is not part of the Robots Exclusion Protocol standard.

The standard does not include any escape character and Google's documentation doesn't mention it either.

Have you tried using the dollar encoded?:

```
Disallow: /%24%7Bobject.path%7D$
```

Comment: I'm afraid that won't match since google bot doesn't percent encode the $ char :/